# Hive tables not found even though database name specified in ODBC connection

Tags: ssis, hive

I am connecting to Hive from SSIS, through the Amazon-supplied ODBC driver for use with EMR.  I am using a connection string like

```
Driver={Amazon Hive ODBC Driver};Host=hostname;Port=10000;Database=dbname
```

when I run a query like `select * from tabname`, I get an error like `HIVE..tabname` not found.  The fully-qualified version `dbname.tabname` works.

Why is the unqualified table name not found - am I not supplying the default database name correctly?

`show tables` returns an empty list, so it looks like the database on the connect string somehow is not being applied.

Comment: can you check `show tables;` that gives you list of tables available in current database.

Comment: empty.  it's like it's pointing at the default DB even though the connect string says otherwise.

Comment: try `use dbname;`

Comment: its set dbname as database and then u will be able to used it.